# Disqus Wordpress plugin not counting up comments correctly

Tags: wordpress, disqus

I'm running WordPress 3.4 and Disqus 2.72.

I have a problem - every time I write up a comment I find Disqus doesn't count it up.

For example:

**On the list of blog entries it displays 0 comments**

[image]

**When you open up the blog entry it displays 3 comments**

[image]

You can find this at my website: http://www.mac-nutrition.com/category/blogs/

So far I've added the following code to my theme's *functions.php* file but it hasn't really helped (right at the end):

```
// Disqus: Prevent from replacing comment count
remove_filter('comments_number', 'dsq_comments_text');
remove_filter('get_comments_number', 'dsq_comments_number');
remove_action('loop_end', 'dsq_loop_end');
```

I have also tried using the Web Ninja Comment Fixer (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/web-ninja-comment-count-fixer/) but with no success.

Here are my Disqus settings at the moment:

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling the 'Comment Counts' checkbox under Advanced Options in the Disqus plugin. This will output Disqus JavaScript in the footer and should fix this.

If that doesn't work, this may be caused by your current theme or a plugin. You can test this by temporarily reverting to the default WordPress theme. If that doesn't fix this, try disabling all plugins except for Disqus.

Let us know if you still see issues — feel free to tweet again!

Answer (score 1):

I see Amanda Nudelman already answered. Normally, what Amanda mentioned would be the best answer and it is indeed the correct recommendation in this scenario.

However, in this case it looks like you're using the Thesis theme. As Thesis uses non-standard WordPress comment count code the Disqus plugin is unable to recognize the comment count links in order to replace them. Thus the counts continue to reflect the counts from WordPress itself rather than Disqus.

This is something we're unable to address in the Disqus plugin itself and we'd recommend reaching out to Thesis' developer directly.

Regarding the comment count persisting at 0, this is because comments are not currently being synced back to WordPress with Disqus 2012 enabled. We just together a fix for that and are currently testing it; it will be released in the next plugin update very soon. Comments will then sync back to WordPress regularly and the counts will essentially reflect the numbers in Disqus.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to say that in 2013 Disqus introduced a "patch" checkbox for exactly that problem by default. Does the job!

To see this, go into your plugins and click "Settings" in the DISQUS plugin row.

[image: Wordpress comments always show 0 with disqus]